# files aren't generated using Swagger codegen plugin

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-codegen

I can't generate the models / controllers / services in any way, I run this command mvn clean install but it generates the files in target/generate-sources,I have used json but also yaml, How can I make this generate it for me in src/main?

Here is my pom.xml , project - https://github.com/FreeTrainingZone/identityverification-repo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.freetrainingzone</groupId>
    <artifactId>identityverification </artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>identityverification </name>
    <description>Identity Verification  REST API</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <reqjson.file>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/identityverificationservice.json</reqjson.file>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.13</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>

                <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.33</version>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.github.jknack</groupId>
                        <artifactId>handlebars</artifactId>
                        <version>4.3.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>request-service</id>
                        <!--
                        <goals>

                            <goal>generate</goal>

                        </goals>
                        -->
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${reqjson.file}</inputSpec>
                            <artifactId>contract-service</artifactId>
                            <output>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/swagger</output>
                            <language>spring</language>
                            <generateApis>true</generateApis>
                            <generateModels>true</generateModels>
                            <modelPackage>com.freetrainingzone.identityverification.model</modelPackage>
                            <apiPackage>com.freetrainingzone.identityverification.controller.api</apiPackage>
                            <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
                            <configOptions>
                                <interfaceOnly>false</interfaceOnly>
                                <library>spring-boot</library>
                                <singleContentTypes>true</singleContentTypes>
                                <sourceFolder>/</sourceFolder>
                                <dateLibrary>java17</dateLibrary>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: target/generated-sources is where they belong.  Why do you want them somewhere else?  They will still get compiled.

Comment: but i want these files being generated in src/main where my project is

Comment: You shouldn’t.  You want the code that you wrote to be in a separate place from the code that is generated.  Generated code is generally awful code that is minimally functional.  Maven will compile the code in both places anyway, so why muddle your own work with lousy generated code?

Comment: So if you want the generated code in src/main , would you have to copy it? , I work in a company that simply updates the project when doing an mvn install, but in src/main ,it  uses open api, but isn't swagger basically the same?

Comment: Why do you need the generated code to be in src/main?

Comment: because i want to use this in my project, , So how can I use that generated code in my project?

Comment: It is already being used.  Maven will already compile the source files in target/generated-source.  You don’t have to take any other action.  You don’t need to move them to src/main.  Java compilers can compile source files from multiple locations.

Comment: And how can I import these classes to my project? sorry for my ignorance

Comment: You can use `import` statements just like with any other class, but as far as I know, there is no way to make an IDE recognize classes before they’re generated.  They will appear in the IDE as errors, but you can still compile successfully.

Comment: well , then i get it , anyway it does not make sense to generate it since the project is going to be full of errors

Comment: The Swagger definition is the master definition.  By generating the code every time, your project can be certain that it is using types and operations compatible with the Swagger definition.  That will be especially important if the Swagger definition file is updated later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify file gradle/swagger.gradle

```
openApiGenerate {
    outputDir = "$rootDir".toString()
```

Modify file pom.xml

```
<configuration>
    <output>${project.basedir}/src/main</output>
```

Comment: i'm using maven , does it work in the same way?

Comment: Sorry, the above gradle setting is what I'm using.

Your can use this in your pom.xml:
<output>${project.basedir}/src/main</output>

Comment: it's in inside <configuration> ?

Comment: Yes, please search keyword "output".

Comment: i tried it but doesn't work

Comment: well, i did it! WOW